# Connect Xamarin app with RESTful Web Service

Tags: xamarin, restful-architecture

I am new in the Xamarin area and I am trying to learn how to connect it with online database. I saw some tutorials which tell to connect it with RESTful Web Service but I have confused.

Does any one can tell any good tutorial or can give me some instructions how to connect it?

Comment: Don't think these types of questions belong here, but I would look at any C# RESTful Web Service tutorials as this type of action is not specific to Xamarin, but all of ASP.NET.

Comment: If you've already read a tutorial and are still confused, try asking specifically about the thing that is confusing you, instead of just asking us to point you to another tutorial.  Using RESTful services in C# is some that has been documented thousands of times on the web.  Finally, asking for pointers to tutorials or other resources is specifically prohibited on SO.